# npm install gives errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't succeed with npm install packages
after $npm install, it shows this output:

```
> canvas@1.6.7 install /home/samuel/testes/Avanade Angular Academy by Gama/gama-avanade-tryout01/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

./util/has_lib.sh: 31: ./util/has_lib.sh: pkg-config: not found
gyp: Call to './util/has_lib.sh freetype' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/samuel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/samuel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/samuel/testes/Avanade Angular Academy by Gama/gama-avanade-tryout01/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@1.6.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.6.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/samuel/.npm/_logs/2017-12-12T02_40_55_700Z-debug.log
```

What should I do? Thanks for all of you help!

Comment: "A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/samuel/.npm/_logs/2017-12-12T02_40_55_700Z-debug.log"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to install some external dependencies. The commands below were enough.

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++
```

After this, $npm install works!

Comment: Hello , where to install these command ?   i am getting **'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**

Comment: @Anuj, you are probably logged in as root user, you don't need to write `sudo`.

Comment: perfect i was waiting for this asnwer from past 2020

Comment: fwiw this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

delete node modules and package-lock.json

1.yarn install or npm install
2.npm start

Comment: where does it say that OP uses yarn? Please add more example code on why your answer works better than the already approved one.